# Dynamically add element to DOM in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

This is how my page looks like on initial load

```
<body>
 <div class="col-md-12" id="dataPanes">
   <div class="row dataPane"> Chunk of html elements </div>
 </div>

 <div class"col-md-12 text-right">
   <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add dynamic row" ng-click="addElementChunk()" />
</body>
```

I am in need to add rows to div#dataPanes on button click 
If I was using jQuery,addElementChunk() function would have looked as below

```
var addElementChunk = function()
{
   var html = "<div class='row dataPane'> Chunk of html elements </div>";
   $("#dataPanes").append(html);
}
```

> but how do I implement the same in angular??

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

> Compiles an HTML string or DOM into a template and produces a template function, which can then be used to link scope and the template together.

and [`$sce`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)

> Strict Contextual Escaping (SCE) is a mode in which AngularJS constrains bindings to only render trusted values. Its goal is to assist in writing code in a way that (a) is secure by default, and (b) makes auditing for security vulnerabilities such as XSS, clickjacking, etc. a lot easier.

```
addElementChunk = function(){ 
    var html = '<div class="row dataPane"> Chunk of html elements </div>';
    var trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(html);
    var compiledHtml = $compile(trustedHtml)($scope);
    angular.element(document.getElementById('dataPanes')).append(compiledHtml);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! But I am wondering if I can load a html template inside $compile function since my html is quite big

Comment: roughly 100 lines of html

Comment: @Kgn-web, Then  I would advise you to create a directive and then use `$compile`

Answer (score 1):

you can append new div using angular ng-repeat directive

lets say you have an array that contain one element and every time you click the button you add another element to the array, while you are repeating it in your "dataPane" div

so you code could be:

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtr">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="dataPanes">
        <div class="row dataPane" ng-repeat="element in added_elements"> Chunk of html elements ( {{element}} ) </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add dynamic row" ng-click="addMoreElements()" />
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
angular
.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtr', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.added_elements = ["elem 1"];
    $scope.addMoreElements = function(){
        $scope.added_elements.push("elem "+ ($scope.added_elements.length+1));
    } 
}])
```

so you can add whatever data you want about your repeated row and bind it in html in simple way without having to repeat the whole html code

[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Aya_Salama/gd57323b/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also append a new html element in this way. I think its very easy to write and also understand. hope it will help you. 
angular.element used to access the html element.
 Here is the html code:

```js
 angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
 
   $scope.addElementChunk = function()
    {
       var htmlStr = '<div class="row dataPane"> Chunk of html elements </div>';
      debugger;
      angular.element(document.getElementById('dataPanes')).append(htmlStr);
    }
          
 });
```

```html
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

 <div class="col-md-12" id="dataPanes">
   <div class="row dataPane"> Chunk of html elements </div>
 </div>

 <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
   <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add dynamic row" ng-click="addElementChunk()" />
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/biswajit_rout/f1o0jj58/1/)